# jQuery multiplication rounding down by a little

Tags: multiplication, rounding-error

I am trying to do a pretty simple multiplication using the following script:

```
$('.itemRow.item').each(function(){
    var qty = $(this).find('input.quantity').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.claculatedPrice').data('price');
    var total = qty * price;

    $(this).find('.claculatedPrice').text(total);
});
```

The code above produces the following values:

```
qty = 7
price = 435.59
total = 3049.1299999999997
```

I would expect the total to be: 3049.13 - what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
total.toFixed(2);
```

The above will work

JS will calculate with precision points. You can round it off by using `.toFixed` to 2 places